# Simple Java constructors and setters to create user profiles

Tags: java, oop, methods, constructor, setter

I have a question about an assignment I'm doing. I'll give the main code and the methods in question so its clear what I'm asking

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MyBookDriver {

    private static final Scanner KBD = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        // Constructors
        MyBookAccount bbSheldon = new MyBookAccount("Sheldon", true);
        MyBookAccount bbPenny = new MyBookAccount("Penny", false);
        MyBookAccount bbAmy = new MyBookAccount("Amy", "Montreal", true);
        MyBookAccount bbLeonard = new MyBookAccount("Leonard");
        System.out.println("\n" + MyBookAccount.getNumAccounts()
                + " MyBook accounts have been created.");

        // Mybook ID
        System.out.println("\nMyBook Accounts:");
        System.out.println("    Sheldon's ID: " + bbSheldon.ID);
        System.out.println("    Penny's ID: " + bbPenny.ID);
        System.out.println("    Amy's ID: " + bbAmy.ID);
        System.out.println("    Leonard's ID: " + bbLeonard.ID);
        pause();

        // logged in
        System.out.println("\nMyBook Accounts:");
        System.out.println("    Sheldon is " 
                + (bbSheldon.isLoggedIn() ? "" : "not ") + "logged in");
        System.out.println("    Penny is " 
                + (bbPenny.isLoggedIn() ? "" : "not ") + "logged in");
        System.out.println("    Amy is " 
                + (bbAmy.isLoggedIn() ? "" : "not ") + "logged in");
        System.out.println("    Leonard is " 
                + (bbLeonard.isLoggedIn() ? "" : "not ") + "logged in");
        pause();

        //post a wall message 
        System.out.println("\nPosting wall update:");
        bbSheldon.setWallPost("I like flags!");
        bbPenny.setWallPost("Looking for a job.");
        bbLeonard.setWallPost("I'm just hoping I can date a girl "
                + "from next door.");
        System.out.println("    Sheldon's: " + bbSheldon.getWallPost() + "\n"
                + "    Penny's: " + bbPenny.getWallPost() + "\n"
                + "    Amy's: " + bbAmy.getWallPost() + "\n"
                + "    Leonard's: " + bbLeonard.getWallPost() + "\n");
        pause();

        //Sending messages
        System.out.println("\nSending messages:");
        bbLeonard.sendMessage(bbPenny, "Will you go out with me tonight?");
        bbAmy.sendMessage(bbSheldon, "Neuroscience is a real science.");
        bbPenny.sendMessage(bbAmy, "What a nice picture.");
        checkMessages(bbSheldon);
        checkMessages(bbPenny);
        checkMessages(bbAmy);
        checkMessages(bbLeonard);
        pause();

        //toString
        System.out.println("\nDisplaying info:");
        System.out.println(bbSheldon);
        System.out.println(bbPenny);
        System.out.println(bbAmy);
        System.out.println(bbLeonard);
        pause();
    }

    private static void checkMessages(MyBookAccount user) {
        MyBookAccount aFriend;
        aFriend = user.getFriend();
        if (aFriend != null) {
            System.out.println("    " + user.getName() + "'s message from " 
                    + aFriend.getName()
                    + " is " + user.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("    " + user.getName() + " has no messages");
        }
    }

    private static void pause() {
        System.out.print("\n...press enter...");
        KBD.nextLine();
    }

}
```

one of the methods takes this name and these parameters and is a setter for two properties, "message" and "friend"

```
sendMessage(MyBookAccount to, String message)
```

How do I make a setter that manipulates multiple properties?

Comment: Do you just need `this.friend = to; this.message = message;`?

Comment: Why do you want to "make a setter that manipulates multiple properties"? Make a method to accept 2 pieces of data that itself calls appropriate setters (or updates the fields directly).

Comment: I think he doesn't know what "setter" means.  Because the hypothetical `sendMessage` method he is talking about would not function like a setter.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this until you show us the code for your MyBookAccount class.

Answer (score 1):

I would not make a setter to manipulate more than one property. This can make your code confusing and more difficult to maintain in the future. It would be better to make a method that is able to do this instead. Make setters for each field and then have a method that manipulate them in the way that you want.